# in Node REPL, Side effects in promise are run when function is defined, not when it is invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is a behavior of Promises that I didn't anticipate.

I'm getting the hang of promises' asynchronous nature and am creating sequences of promises for control flow. However, I'm worried my control flow's synchronicity is not being respected.

In the following example, it seems like a Promise's side effects are being called when the Promise is *defined*, not when it's run. By "side effects", I specifically mean `console.log` in this example, but in my app I'm also doing a bit of global configuration from within my Promise resolvers.

In this example, I am running a `nodejs` REPL with `v5.11.2`, a relatively recent version.

```
> testFn = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log("called when promise defined");
      resolve("called when promise invoked")
  })
called when promise defined
Promise { 'called when promise invoked' }
> testFn.then(function(res){console.log(res)})
Promise { <pending> }
> called when promise invoked
```

Are promises' `resolve` or `reject` values calculated before the function is invoked? It would seem so in this REPL example. I would have expected the `called when promise defined` string to also be logged when `testFn.then` is called.

Comment: Promises aren't "invoked" at all.  You're misunderstanding promises.

Comment: @SLaks by chaining `then` calls, there's synchronicity. I'm not talking about synchronicity with code that's external to the `then` chain. Only that the order of the `then` calls be preserved with respect to side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new Promise()` constructor takes a function that is invoked *immediately* to provide the initial value of the promise (typically asynchronously).

Calling `then()` after that just consumes that value once it's ready; it doesn't invoke anything.

Comment: I was hoping that  the constructor was only invoked when it's caller comes into scope so that all the side effects wouldn't occur at once. But it appears you're right.

Comment: Elaborating: That is - a promise is a _value_ and not an action, there is no such thing as "executing a promise" - a promise by definition is not something you can execute since it's the value of an already started computation. If you want a "promise you can invoke later" you probably want a _function_ that returns a promise.